# ng-options with object literal data source

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

How do you use ng-options with a object literally where the key of the object is the value and value of object is label. I tried a few suggestions on this site but none seem to work only the default options is showing.

```
   $scope.interviewStatusMessages = {
        "cp": "l'attente de la réponse du candidat",
        "ca": "candidat accepté",
        "cm": "candidat modifiée",
        "cr": "candidat rejeté",
        "ea": "vous avez accepté",
        "em": "vous avez modifié, en attendant la réponse du candidat",
        "ec": "vous avez annulé",
        "ic": "terminé"
    }
```

I tried

```
<select
    ng-options="interviewStatus for (key, label) in interviewStatusMessages">
    <option value="">-- filter interviews --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
  <select ng-model="selectedStatus" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in interviewStatusMessages">
     <option value="">Select Status</option>
  </select>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qnPtkE6wXdFpR3mCKlnv?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know  that ng-model has to be specified to just see the available options.

Comment: @ericsicons yes ng-model is required as can be seen on the Arguments table mid-page [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)